# View with pinch zoom support by default in android

Tags: android, image, zooming, pinch

Is there any view that supports pinch zoom by default with out our changes for pinch zoom ? Need to perform draw operations on Image so looking for onTouch support also.

what is the view type is used when we launch image from myfiles image list?

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at any of the code from [android-pinch](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/)?